# gcsfuse reporting strange permission errors

Tags: gcloud, gcsfuse

I'm trying to use a Google Cloud storage bucket as a mount in Ubuntu 23.04 on Google Cloud.

The command I'm running is:

```
/usr/bin/gcsfuse -o rw --uid 0 --gid 33 --dir-mode 770  --file-mode 770 {NAME OF BUCKET} /var/www/storage-bucket
```

0 is root.
33 is www-data.
I'm just hard coding that for now. I could use --uid $(id -u www-data) --gid $(id -g www-data)

It mounts the bucket. But as root, I cannot make a folder. I get a permission denied.

It's permissions in bash look fine:
drwxrwx---  1 root     www-data        0 Dec 13 23:00 storage-bucket/

If I change `-o rw` to `-o allow_other` I can "touch" a file. But then I get an error that I can't close the file. If I try to edit the file in nano or something, it will not save. I get a permission denied.

I didn't see anything in syslog other than it starting successfully.

Any ideas?

Comment: By default, new Compute Engine instances are assigned read-only permission to Google Cloud Storage. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts#accesscopesiam 1) Check the VM Access Scopes in the Google Cloud web GUI. 2) Check that the assigned service account has the correct IAM role to write Cloud Storage.

Comment: (facepalm) I knew that and forgot to check. Thanks so much! That worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting this as a community for the benefits of others.

---

As mentioned by @John Hanley:

> By default, new Compute Engine instances are assigned read-only permission to Google Cloud Storage. [Access Scopes](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts#accesscopesiam) 1) Check the VM Access Scopes in the Google Cloud web GUI. 2) Check that the assigned service account has the correct IAM role to write Cloud Storage.